# Error in gnls step halving factor

Tags: r, self-study, nonlinear-regression

I am getting an error running a gnls() on some data I have.  I was able to converge using nlsLM(), but I ran into some autocorrelation in my errors, so I want to try to use gnls() so that I will be able to take into account the correlation of my errors.

My data:

```
 > current_tree
site location tree age.base height dbh.cm volume age.bh tree.ID
2     1        1    1       20    4.2    4.6      5   9.67     1.1
3     1        1    1       30    9.3   10.2     38  19.67     1.1
4     1        1    1       40   14.9   14.9    123  29.67     1.1
5     1        1    1       50   19.7   18.3    263  39.67     1.1
6     1        1    1       60   23.0   20.7    400  49.67     1.1
7     1        1    1       70   25.8   22.6    555  59.67     1.1
8     1        1    1       80   27.4   24.1    688  69.67     1.1
9     1        1    1       90   28.8   25.5    820  79.67     1.1
10    1        1    1      100   30.0   26.5    928  89.67     1.1
11    1        1    1      110   30.9   27.3   1023  99.67     1.1
12    1        1    1      120   31.8   28.1   1104 109.67     1.1
13    1        1    1      130   32.4   28.6   1156 119.67     1.1
14    1        1    1      140   33.1   29.0   1219 129.67     1.1
```

Here is the code I am running:

```
> library(nlme)
> expon_model <- function(theta1, theta2, theta3, x){
+   #theta1 is the asymptote
+   theta1*(1 - exp( theta2* ( x^theta3 )))
+ }
> Exponential <- gnls(dbh.cm ~ expon_model(t1, t2, t3, age.bh), 
+                    data=current_tree, start=list(t1=30, t2=0, t3=1))
Error in gnls(dbh.cm ~ expon_model(t1, t2, t3, age.bh), data = current_tree,  : 
  step halving factor reduced below minimum in NLS step
```

In case this helps, when I ran this with nlsLM(), I converged without having to pick very good starting values, but I changed my starting values in this case to be very close to what nlsLM() converged to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the argument `control = gnlsControl (nlstol = 0.01)` inside the gnls() function. This argument controls the tolerance of the algorithm to find the minimum local and expands the number of iterations on nls procedure. Other function is `control = gnlsControl (maxIter = 500)` that controls the number of iterations only.
This is the way to change the default parameters of the otimization algorithm of the `gnls()` function. Your problem is typical when the starting values is so far of the local minimum. A solution to give best starting values is using the function `deriv()` with the first derivatives when the model is quite complex as yours.

Comment: this answer is very short for CV's standards. Could you at least explain what this argument does, and how it would help towards fixing the issue? Thanks!